# I travelled on a visit visa to the USA but then have been rejected 5 times

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, serial-refusals

I was first denied the B1/B2 visa. On my second attempt, I was given the visa for 3 months with an annotation “CPA EXAM - Maryland.” I took the exam and, out of two parts, I passed one part. But, in the same interview, the officer had told me you have to attempt all four parts and I am giving you one chance.

I returned within the stipulated time. Since then, I have reapplied five more times for a visa (on average once a month) and I have not been given the visa.

One more thing: after coming back, I told the officer that I would like to stay for 5 months as I want to pass my remaining exams during the stay. Also, the officer misunderstood my results and he recorded as if I had failed the two parts.

In my last interrview, the visa officer told me to "try to change your circustances and apply after a long time.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Please  follow the advice given by the officer, religiously . It is the best possible advice.

You should reapply only after your circumstances have changed considerably and after a long time. 5 refusals back to back are really really a big deal.

Stop trying for now. If you can afford it, reapply only with the help of an immigration specialist.

Comment: its been 2 years  since last refusal.. also that i have started a companyof my own .. wd worth of 150000 usd. so shall i apply now  or wait more ..and i will re apply for same exam?

Comment: Since your financial standing is strong now, given the adverse history I would suggest you take help of an immigration lawyer.

Comment: @asfandyar If it has been two years since your last refusal, and your circumstances have changed, please edit this information into the question. It would really help people to understand your situation

Comment: It would also be helpful to know your citizenship

Comment: What is your objective in seeking this particar qualification? Might it be seen as a signal of immigrant intent?

Comment: @Traveller indeed.  If "CPA EXAM" means the certified public accountant exam, it might be worth explaining why passing that exam would be useful.  It looks like the asker of the question is seeking a professional qualification in a country where he or she is not authorized to work, which seems puzzling.

Comment: @asfandyar While it may be signaling immigrant intent, also note that the premise of your visit may be challenged, as the same [CPA exam is offered in many locations outside of the US](https://nasba.org/exams/internationalexam/)

Comment: @Giorgio which is precisely the reason why the OP should take the exam on one of these alternate locations and not in the USA. After five rejections, the OP is unlikely to get a visa to the USA in the next five or six years.